# Weighted Choice in Numpy does not return list with exact input probability

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of objects ['P1','P2','P3'] with [0.8,0.1,0.1] as corresponding weights.

I found out numpy choice takes weight as input, but I dont see the output list to exactly match the input probability

Code:

```
draw = [choice(['P1','P2','P3'],p=[0.8,0.1,0.1]) for _ in range(10)]
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(draw))
```

I expected draw to be always contain 8 instances of P1, 1 of P2 and 1 of P3.

But I see that it varies from run to run when using the above code.

Sample output:

```
Run 1:
Counter({'P1': 7, 'P2': 2, 'P3': 1})

Run 2:
Counter({'P1': 10})

Run 3:
Counter({'P1': 9, 'P2': 1})
```

Am I missing something or is this expected output?

Comment: *"I found out numpy choice takes weight as input, but I dont see the output list to exactly match the input probability"*  That is to be expected.  If you rolled a fair six-sided [die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice) six times, you wouldn't expect to get each value exactly once, would you?  The weights are just probabilities, not exact proportions.

Comment: Understood. My understanding was incorrect. Is there any functionality which I can use to get the outcome I am looking for?

Comment: @navycut I have edited my answer to show the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) of `numpy.random.choice` tells you that the argument `p` is the probabilities associated with each entry. And if not given, uniform probability is assumed.

Uniform probability means that the probability of selecting any of the items is equal. **But it does not mean that the number of outcomes will be proportional to the probability always**.

Example : When tossing a coin probability of getting a head equals probability of getting a tail. But will I always get 5 heads and 5 tails when I toss it 10 times? No.

```
toss=[np.random.choice(["head","tail"]) for _ in range(10)]
print(Counter(toss)) #Counter({'head': 7, 'tail': 3})
```

Similarly in your case, you have only mentioned that probability of getting a `P1` is 0.8, but that does not mean you will always see 8 `P1`s when randomly chosen 10 times, it only means that probability of getting it is significantly  higher than the rest.

**EDIT** :

To get the functionality you needed, you can write a function that replicates the item of the list. Given the probability (p=0.8) and ht total number of items (n=10), the number of times it should be replicated is `p*n`

```
def MyDist(elements,weights,num):
    a=[]
    for i in range(len(elements)):
        a+=[elements[i]]*int(weights[i]*num)
    return a

MyDist(['P1','P2','P3'],[0.8,0.1,0.1],10)
#['P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3']
```

Comment: "...it only means that probability of getting it is significantly higher than the rest" – I think it's better to rephrase that in terms of convergence, because significance is a separate beast. In the limitting condition, where the bumber of trials approaches infinity, P1's fraction converges on the probability.

Comment: Thanks Sruthi! The above implementation combined with ramdom.shuffle() to achieve random sequence is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

use `np.repeat` and `np.random.shuffle`

```
def draw(elements, counts):
    out =  np.repeat(elements, counts)
    np.random.shuffle(out)
    return out

draw(['P1','P2', 'P3'], [8,1,1])
Out: 
array(['P1', 'P3', 'P2', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1'], 
      dtype='<U2')
```